# How to efficiently refactor in a qooxdoo project

Tags: javascript, refactoring, package, qooxdoo

I am just working on a big qooxdoo project and want to refactor it. For example, i want to move a class, that is referenced quite often from one package path (app.ui.) to another (app.view.), change variable names. Normal refactoring stuff.

In comparision to Delphi or C#, this seems to be terribly painful with a qooxdoo javascript project.

Is there any easy and uncomplicated way to do this?

FYI: I edit the project with gedit in linux mint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

moving a class shoud be easy within a qooxdoo project because usually every occurance is referenced absolut which means you can use your editor and "search an replace" the whole thing. The only thing you have to do additionally is to move the file to the desired location and thats it. So its more a question of the editor than of the file structure.

Best,
Martin